# How to find a writable file owned by root?

Tags: linux, find

How can I find a file on my hard drive created by root that has write permissions?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Where are you looking for the file? Do you know any specifics about the file (name, type, etc)?

Comment: use the `find` command and the `-perm` switch. I don't get the title of your question...

Comment: yes ... may you give me a find command for it ... Tnx

Comment: have you tried the answer below from @Jaidev-Sridhar ?

Comment: Sorry, but did you even bother to read `man find`? All the answers point you to that and that is for a reason.

Answer (score 10):

To look for a file matching multiple conditions with `find`, simply list each condition in turn. For example, to look for a file owned by root (`-user root`) and writable by its owner (`-perm -u+w`) on the root filesystem (`-xdev`, meaning not to recurse underneath mount points such as `/proc` and `/sys`) and called `hello`:

```
find / -xdev -user root -perm -u+w -name hello
```

If you're looking for world-writable files, replace `-u+w` by `-a+w`. (The `-` before the permissions means that the file must have at least these permissions; without it `find` would look for a file having exactly the specified permissions.) With GNU find, you can also look for a file that is writable by the user running `find`: replace `-perm -u+w` by `-writable`.

Answer (score 2):

```
find / -uid 0 -perm u+w,g+w,o+w
```

If you want writable by others, just have o+w.

Comment: I created `ex.pl` previously and chmodded it to 777, and then executed your command, but the command didn't find `ex.pl`. What's wrong?

Comment: You can condense `u+w,g+w,o+w` into `a+w`. But you need to tell `find` to look for a file having *at least* these permissions: `-perm -a+w`.

Comment: @Ejder did you create the file as user root?

Answer (score -2):

Most of the time, people who want to escalate the current privileges, are interested in finding the files with write permissions.

This will list all the files with '777' permission -rwxrwxrwx

```
find / -type f -user root -perm u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rwx 2>/dev/null
```

If we are interested in all the files owned by root and others having write permission

```
find / -type f -user root -perm /o=w 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: “… people … are interested in finding the files with write permissions.” Yes, that’s exactly what the question is asking. And your answer is not good.  (1) If `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` are 666, that’s a vulnerability. But your command won’t find them because they aren’t executable. (2) For a file to be protected 733 is rare, but it is world-writable (even though it isn’t world-readable) and can open a vulnerability. But your command won’t find it because it isn’t world-readable. (3) Worst of all for hacker wannabes, your command won’t find files that are 4777 or 6777 (setuid + writable).

Comment: For that reason, I have provided the second command which can find all files, if the other user is having a write permission. No matter what, if the file has SUID or GUID bit set or if it's world readable or writable or having execute privileges, it will list those files. Please check the second command and try if it works for all the possibilities which are mentioned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).